# How can I make my asp calendar a popup?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net, calendar

I have a calendar in asp.net that is shown when a user clicks on a textbox. However, I'm not sure how to display the calendar without pushing all the content below. I need a way to make a popup panel for the calendar.

This is what I have so far. I'm just using a table in order to position the calendar directly below the textbox but this is changing the layout of the items below my table.

```
<asp:Table runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnClick="showCal('Calendar1')"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>       
    </asp:TableRow>
     <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" style="display: none;"></asp:Calendar>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

notice that I have my calendar set to display:none. My onclick js function fires when someone clicks on the textbox.

I've tried to change the z-index of my second table row in the hopes that when the calendar is shown, the rest of my page wont be changed but that didn't work.

Comment: this is more of a css question. Essentially you'll need to review what css declarations have been made and then adjust accordingly. Additionally you may need to override the canned asp JS that accomplishes this with your own

Comment: Use AjaxToolKit from nuget packages

Comment: @BrandtSolovij I am facing exact issue as of OP. I don't have the *choice* to use `AjaxToolKit's CalendarExtender`. So if you can elaborate an answer that would just great. And roshambo, +1 for asking the question. If you have found a solution please share.

Comment: Essentially, from the question posed - roshambo's issue amounts to how the elements are nested and styled as well as the dom elements which these tags create. `asp:Table` will create just that, a table element. Table elements have intrinsic css properties as do rows and cells, that may conflict with what you guys are trying to accomplish with the Calendar popup interaction. If you can provide a link i can take a look at your html and css and make a recommendation, but without that ability - "spiritual guidance" is the best form of an answer available. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by just applying the following CSS to my calendar:

```
calendarClass{
    background: white; 
    position: absolute;
}
```

somehow adding a white background (or whichever color you'd like) takes the transparency away from the calendar so that it doesn't look strange. The position absolute then makes the calendar appear on top of the table.